# Helper method using map to create array, but no array is created?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and programming in general. I am trying to pull the top20 streamers from twitch, I can do this, then I format the information into my own array of hashes, the console output looks fine, but I cant assign the array of hashes to a variable to then utilize.

So this

```
def get_top
      top_twitch=twitch_id.get_streams({language: "en"}).data
      @top20 = top_twitch.each_with_index.map do |s, idx|
        { "rank#{idx+1}": { game_name: s.game_name,
                  title: s.title,
                  game_id: s.game_id,
                  thumbnail: s.thumbnail_url,
                  user_name: s.user_name,
                  viewer_count: s.viewer_count } }
    end
```

Outputs this

```
3.1.2 :085 > helper.get_top
 => 
[{:rank1=>                       
   {:game_name=>"Rocket League",
    :title=>"First Touch Pre-Show | RLCS Winter Major | Group Stage",
    :game_id=>"30921",
    :thumbnail=>"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_rocketleague-{width}x{height}.jpg",
    :user_name=>"RocketLeague",
    :viewer_count=>35257}},
 {:rank2=>
   {:game_name=>"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
    :title=>"BLAST.tv Major Europe RMR: B Stream, Day 2 - B8 vs Fnatic",
    :game_id=>"32399",
    :thumbnail=>"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_blast-{width}x{height}.jpg",
    :user_name=>"BLAST",
    :viewer_count=>34514}},
```

But when I try to access the array its not there

```
3.1.2 :086 > top20
(irb):86:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `top20' for main:Object (NameError)
                       
top20                  
^^^^^                  
3.1.2 :087 > @top20
 => nil
```

```
module TwitchHelper
  attr_accessor :top20

    def twitch_id
      client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        
        twitch_auth = Twitch::Client.new(
        client_id: client_id,
        client_secret: client_secret,
        access_token: access_token
        )
    end
    
    def get_top
      top_twitch=twitch_id.get_streams({language: "en"}).data
      @top20 = top_twitch.each_with_index.map do |s, idx|
        { "rank#{idx+1}": { game_name: s.game_name,
                  title: s.title,
                  game_id: s.game_id,
                  thumbnail: s.thumbnail_url,
                  user_name: s.user_name,
                  viewer_count: s.viewer_count } }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.

Comment: Further to @anothermh's point, this is a pure-Ruby question so it should not have a Rails tag. Moreover, as arrays are so common that the tag "arrays" is probably not useful as a filter when searching. I'd just go with "Ruby" as the only tag. Secondly, `get_top` is evidently defined within a class but you've said nothing about that, which may be confusing to readers. Lastly, you've chopped off `]` to end of the array returned by `helper.get_top`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have not associated the instance variable `@top20` with a specific instance of the class you have defined.

Presumably, the variable `helper` holds a class instance (`helper = ClassName.new(...)`).

---

If you've created a getter method for `@top20` you need to write

```
helper.top20
```

A getter can be created by including the instance method

```
def top20
  @top20
end
```

in the class definition. Because getters are needed so often Ruby provides a shortcut for the creation of this method, by including the line

```
attr_reader :top20
```

in the class definition. This invokes the method [Module#attr_reader](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) on the class (when the class is being created), which creates the above-mentioned getter method.

Alternatively, one use [Module#attr_accessor](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) to create both getter and setter methods by including the line

```
attr_accessor :top20
```

in the class definition. The setter method is equivalent to

```
def top20=(x)
  @top20 = x
end
```

and is invoked

```
helper.top20 = x
```

where `x` is a placeholder for the object to be assigned to `@top20`.

---

If you've not created a getter method for `@top20` you need to write

```
helper.instance_variable_get(:@top20)
```

or

```
helper.instance_variable_get("@top20")
```

See [Object#instance_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get).

Comment: I am not sure what class "helper" is. The method used here is located in controllers>helpers>twitch_helper.rb. Ive updated my OP to include that complete file structure as it. It currently does not work, in the console if I run "helper.get_top" it prints out the hash as expected, however the variable @top20 is "=> nil"

Comment: I meant your line `3.1.2 :085 > helper.get_top` suggests that `helper` is an instance of some class (that `include`'s `module TwitchHelper`) that is not shown. `helper.get_top` assigns a value to  `@top20` and since it is the last value computed, `@top20` is returned by that method. `helper.top20` should now return the value of `@top20` as well. I should say that I'm not familiar with `controllers>helpers>twitch_helper.rb`, cause me to wonder if my advice is correct.